# Is emplace_back faster than setting an index?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector

Which would be faster?

```
std::vector< std::string > vec;
vec.reserve(10);
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
    vec.emplace_back("Some text");
}
```

or

```
std::vector< std::string > vec;
vec.resize(10);
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
    vec[i] = "Some Text";
}
```

and if one of them is faster than the other (with size of 10) which one is more scalable?

Comment: Strictly speaking first is slightly slower, because you need to update one pointer in addition to all other operations. But I would prefer it almost in any circumstances over second, because it have less potential for troubles. And if you code need to be optimized so, that you can't spare even one pointer update you probably shouldn't use `std::vector` in such code.

Comment: You're not setting an index in the second snippet, you are assigning the value to an element of the vector by its index. Emplace back is useful when you want to avoid extra copy or move since the object is created in place (with placement new). This is particularly helpful for large objects, but they must be move insertable. I'm not sure in your case the difference would be significant for one or another. Moreover, if you only have a small number of elements in the vector and you don't have large objects you should not be concerned with such optimization.

Comment: The second one has twice the number of constructions, twice the number of destructions and as many moves as constructions (which the first doesn't have) so I should imagine it would be somewhat slower especially as the numbers get larger.

Comment: *"Which would be faster?"* -> measure.

Comment: @Jarod42 runtime obviously..?

Comment: First one seems faster (with a ratio of 1/3) [Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/ZXc9ZVUVav1ifp4axbh2Q6KDiRM).

Comment: @MariusBancila yes, but the extension is "what is more scalable", ie, what if it were 100000000 instead of 10?

Comment: @Jarod42 wow, thats really interesting. would that be due to the lines before the loop, ie, `vec.resize() and reserve and defining it`? Would the results change if all that is declared and the demo is just testing the actual functions `emplace_back` and `vec[i]..`?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> vec(n, "Some Text");`

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili After testing them, that is actually the fastest. `emplace_back` and `index` are about equivalent but that one is just that bit faster. Only issue is that it doesn't hold up for altering the data later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be platform, compiler and compile flags-dependent.

- The `emplace_back` version would need to increment vector `size` each time.
- The indexed version would have to create empty string objects to pre-fill the vector.

So there is no way to tell without analyzing the generated code and/or measuring it.

According to [google benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/ShqIJbZVd5fQfWVWzFrHLq9pcHE), the `emplace_back` version is faster:

**GCC 10.2 -O3**: `emplace_back` slightly faster:

[image]

**Clang 11 -O3**: `emplace_back` is much faster:

[image]

**MSVC 19.6 /O2**: `emplace_back` slightly faster:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark           Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------
Emplace           138 ns          136 ns      4480000
Index             159 ns          160 ns      4977778
```

Comment: That's quite interesting. Could you try this without including the act of declaring the variables and `resizing` and `reserving`, so it just tests the actual functions `emplace_back` and `vec[i]`. As well as a much larger sample? Ie, `1000000`?

Comment: @prtwrt: you have the link to experiment as you want. You can still ask another question to understand the result, if you want.

Comment: @prtwrt But where would the vector creation time go then? Don't you want to know the total time your code takes?

Comment: Yes, to understand the question because its such a small size (10) im wondering if if has primarily to do with the functions `reserve` and `resize`. I'll try play around with it now.

Comment: @rustyx Sure I do, but not repeatidly, rather, the repetition is the act of the `emplace_back` and `vec[i]` since the creation would only occur once..

Comment: @prtwrt - there is also repetition behind `resize`. `resize(N)` must create N instances of empty `std::string`. That is not the case for `reserve`.

Comment: wouldn't `reserve` have to allocate a new set of memory? Also @rustyx, somewhere in your answer (i can't make one) just for visibility, I tried excluding the `reserve and resize and creation` and `vec[i]` runs about 3-4x faster. https://quick-bench.com/q/GS1TVmr0urc5DIXdXqJ53IPuvQY .Oh, nevermind I can now lol

Comment: Yes, memory allocation is O(1). `reserve` only allocates memory, but `resize` allocates memory *and* constructs objects (O(N)).